# Angular ng-bind-html / sanitize does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I added the ngSanitize Module to my app and added the javascript file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('partApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize',  ...]
```

But the html output is only without attributes. For example `myhtml = '<span style="font-size:12px">test</span>'` does only output the span without the style.

```
  <div ng-if="show!==undefined" ng-cloak ng-bind-html="myhtml"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular html-binding does not completely trust interpolated expressions. You need to explicitly tell it to trust a particular expression using $sce service (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

Somewhere in your controller you should have this snippet:

```
myhtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(myhtml);
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use $sce.trustAsHtml... so `ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml()"` in html 
and in controller

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(html){
return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
}
```

or better yet create your own $compile directive such as :

```
app.directive('ngHtmlCompile',function ($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
           // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
          return scope.$eval(attrs.ngHtmlCompile);
        },
        function(value) {
          // when the 'compile' expression changes
          // assign it into the current DOM
          element.html(value);

          // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
          // scope.
          // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
          // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    );
};
```

});

and then use it like so :

```
<span ng-html-compile="html"></span>
```

**EDIT - made minor fix**
here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWZZE/198/) showing the code

Comment: yes, you just need to pass to it a scope html string just like the ng-bind-html.

Comment: you can give it a shot... now

Answer (score 1):

For me was more effective do a filter

```
angular.module('app.filters', [])
.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlCode){
     return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
   }
}]);
```

And in html use:

```
<div ng-if="show!==undefined" ng-cloak ng-bind-html="myhtml | sanitize"></div>
```